# Unable to access nginx forwarded port to AWS remote instance

Tags: ssh, port-forwarding, port, nginx, amazon-web-services

I have an `nginx` running on my local machine which is serving on port 8080. I can't forward that port through the router, but I do have an AWS Linux instance running, over which I have total control.

I have forwarded the port 8080 from the AWS instance as `ssh -N -R 8080:localhost:8080 user@aws_instance`. I have opened the 8080 port through AWS console and disabled firewall in both the machines (just to get it to work). I can access `nginx` from other systems in my LAN, so I know that it's accessible from outside. I also have a `lighttpd` running on the AWS instance to test remote access to the AWS instance, and sure enough port 80 is working.

I can also get the desired reply `curl localhost:8080` *at the AWS* Instance which means that the port is forwarded correctly, but for the love of my life, I can't access that 8080 from anywhere else.

Do I need to host another (perhaps proxy) server at the AWS Instance to access that port? Am I missing some other trick? I simply cannot figure it out. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not using the default Security Group, you need to allow these EC2 instances to talk to each other by adding a rule to allow all traffic from the same Security Group.

Comment: It's an Amazon Lightsail instance, which apart from the configuration and interface, is an EC2 instance, as far as I'm given to understand and there are no other running instances.

I've opened the relevant ports and there's no firewall and I can access port 80 from my workplace. I don't see any other config for security groups in there.